# Octopus deploy can't find SQL Credential when trying to restore a database from Azure using powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, azure, octopus-deploy

I've written a powershell script to `restore from url` a database from Azure. Testing locally on my machine this works fine. When I log into the server and run the script it works fine.

However, if I set up octopus deploy to run the script it is unable to find the SQL credential. This code returns `false`:

```
If (Get-SqlCredential -Name $credentialName -Path $instanceName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue )
```

So I'm thinking that however the octopus tentacle tries to run the script, using LocalSystem, it doesn't have the privileges to get the SQL Credential. Why wouldn't LocalSystem be able to get the Credentials?

Is my suspicion correct? I've noticed that you can run a tentacle under a specific user account but is this the best way to do it? Also, it will have these elevated privileges for every deployment which isn't great as none of the others require any additional privileges.

I'm reluctant to run it under an existing user account and I don't really want to create a new one just for this deployment process.

Are there any alternatives to using another user account? or is the above incorrect and there's another reason for this?

Answer (score 2):

I don't use Octopus for deployments but with any 3rd party tool of this nature in regard to SQL Server...it would always be a best practice to create a deployment account so you ensure least privilege.

A quick search in Octopus` documentation they seem to suggest the same information on having a [deployment account specific to an environment](https://octopus.com/docs/deployment-examples/sql-server-databases):

> Finally, it is good security practice to have a different deployment account per environment. That deployment account only has permissions to make schema changes in their environment. An account used to change a test environment should not be able to change production.

Comment: Good advice. I shall follow this

Answer (score 0):

I have tested using my account for the Octopus Tentacle and it works. So it is indeed an issue with the privileges of the LocalSystem. This, and the documentation Shawn Melton has linked to [here](https://octopus.com/docs/deployment-examples/sql-server-databases) suggest this is the preferred method of doing things.

For those with the same problem, you can change the user account the tentacle uses by opening `Services`, right click on the appropriate `OctopusDeploy Tentacle` (you may have more than one), `Properties`, `Log On`and enter the account details:

[image]